How to get the name of the current route using go_router in Flutter?
Following the changes described in the migration guide, I can access the Uri directly (e.g., /product/123). However, I need to get the name of this route, which is product_details.

are you using v9.0.2 ?

No, the last one (14.1.3)

I fount the answer, just create this extension:
extension GoRouterExtension on GoRouter {
String get currentRouteName => routerDelegate.currentConfiguration.last.route.name;
}


